# Canopen SdoCommunicationError when trying to read RPDO config

Tags: python, can-bus, canopen

I have a peak CAN adapter connected to a device communicating on the CAN with Canopen.
I use canopen library 2.1.0 with python 3.10.0 to create a network, add a node with an eds file and connect.
I'm trying to log all the messages from the bus.
I'm able to see the messages from the device but not the ones I send.
I've tried to use the option receive_own_messages=True in the connect method, but that doesn't change anything. My CAN adapter supports it.

```
import canopen
import can

nw = canopen.Network()
node = nw.add_node(1, r"C:\path\to\eds")
nw.listeners += [can.Printer()]
nw.connect(interface='pcan', bitrate=125000, channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', receive_own_messages=True)
node.rpdo.read()
```

CAN trace:
[image]

As you can see, the messages coming from the device are there (0x701, 0x581) but not the ones I send (I expect 0x601 as this is the COB-ID used for SDO request).

Any idea how can I make this work?

Comment: Looks like some filtering is enabled because those 0x581 ought to be replies to your 0x601. I'd consider getting a better CAN listening tool.

Comment: I can confirm that no filters are applied. I also get the same result if I start transmitting rpdo (so when the rpdo is sent by the canopen lib, similar to 0x601). I'd expect to see 0x201 in the trace as this is the COB-ID of the rpdo, but can't see it. Although if I connect an external CAN sniffing tool like PCAN Viewer, I can see the frames.

Comment: So use the good tool which lets you see the frames... I'm not sure that this is even a programming question tbh.

Comment: `node.rpdo.read()` will show you only the received PDOs while `node.tpdo.read()` should show you sent PDOs. See the [doc](https://canopen.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network.html#canopen.RemoteNode)

Comment: @Lundin I’m not sure why this is so complicated to understand. I’m using this library to read and write from/to a canopen node. It provides methods to read the CAN bus, which only partly work in this case, so I’m looking for answers from people who’ve potentially been there. Why do you think they bothered developing this library if people could just go use “that other tool that works”? I need something I can automate! Smh

Comment: @Tranbi thanks but that shouldn’t make any difference, similarly to rpdo.read(), tpdo.read() function triggers an SDO read of a bunch of parameters to read the desired PDO configuration. So it will send requests with cob-id 0x601 and expect responses in 0x581 (because my node ID is 1). As I said in the description, in this case I can only see what I receive (0x581), but not the 0x601 sent through the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the PCAN-Basic API (under Windows?) for connectivity:

https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interfaces/pcan.html

This low-level API doesn't offer the self-receive feature so the parameter receive_own_messages=True is ineffective. If you have a Linux development platform (e.g. Raspberry Pi, Linux virtual machine with USB pass-through support) you could switch to PCAN under SocketCAN which supports it:

https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interfaces/socketcan.html#socketcan-pcan

Comment: I see... Thank you for the info. I just can't understand then how is it that I can see the sent messages when I read the bus with PCAN viewer parallelly to my script sending messages using that same adapter...

Comment: It's because PCAN-Viewer uses a different API. It's from the vendor so their own tools have full access. For customers, there is only the free basic and the commercial Developer API but you'll be hard pressed to find any open-source tools supporting that one.
https://www.peak-system.com/CAN-API-Vergleich.392.0.html?&L=1&sword_list%5B0%5D=pcanapi